# jQuery highlight the found characters found with :contains?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I got a big list with some content
For eg:

```
<ol>
    <li id="1">Content1</li>
    <li id="2">Content2</li>
    <li id="3">Content3</li>
    <li id="4">Content4</li>
    <li id="5">Content5</li>
    <li id="6">Content6</li>
    <li id="7">Content7</li>
    <li id="8">Content8</li>
    <li id="9">Content9</li>
    <li id="10">Content10</li>
    <li id="11">Content11</li>
    <li id="12">Content12</li>
    <li id="13">Content13</li>
</ol>
```

Now when i do a js like this :

```
$("li").hide();
$("li:contains('Content1')").show();
```

This will make ONLY the li's with the `Content1` visible but what i want is the should also highlight the found **characters** maybe by adding a class to only those characters or by any other method.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/NbBsn/)

```
$("li:contains('Content1')").each(function(){
    var content = "Content1";
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(content,"<span>"+content+"</span>")
})
```

This should work.

Comment: have a look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/kritya/NbBsn/2/  How do i get this one working ?